# Adding strings to files without overwriting the previous strings

Tags: c++, string, file

I have two questions. I m working on a problem based on files.

Here is my first program.

```
    ofstream outRegister( "account.dat", ios::out );
    if ( !outRegister    ) {
    cerr << "File could not be opened" << endl;
    exit( 1 );}
    cout<<"enter your username :";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"enter your password :";
    cin>>b;
    outRegister<<a<<' '<<b;
    cout<<"your account has been created";
```

everytime i run this code, my progrm gets data from user and stores in the "account.dat" file, but by overwriting the previous ones. How can i code my program to write them in the next line?

And my second question is,

whenever i need to login, i need my program to search for that particular username and password given by user from the "account.dat" file.If it matches it should allow accesss.

```
ifstream inRegister( "account.dat", ios::in );
if ( !inRegister     ) {
cerr << "File could not be opened" << endl;
exit( 1 );
}
string a,a1,b,b1;

cout<<"\nyou are a premium user\n\n"<<endl;
cout<<"\n enter your user name:\t";
cin>>a;

while(getline(inRegister,a1))
{
if(a1==a)
{
    cout<<"\n enter your password: \t";
    cin>>b;
    inRegister>>b1;
    if(b1==b)
    {
        cout<<"\n access granted logging in....\n\n";
        Allowaccess();
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\n you have entered a wrong password";
    }
}
else
    cout<<"\n no such user name is found";
}
```

is my second coding correct?If not, Can anyone guide me how to use the getline function properly?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the append file mode `app`, whose behaviour is documented as

> All output operations happen at the end of the file, appending to its
>   existing contents.

```
ofstream outRegister("account.dat", ios::app);
```

For your second question, try using [ifstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/) and [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) to process the file line by line, checking whether the first word in the line matches your target username.

Try the second part yourself and post a question, including your code to date, if you get stuck.

Comment: u mean,using getline in while loop and checking with my string?

Comment: @JefreeSujit I've added a little more detail on `app` mode.  Yes, I did mean that you should write a loop which calls `getline` and parses the string this returns.  I've updated my answer to be more specific here too.

Comment: thanks.. i coded the second thing, but got stuck in first one...so i couldn't get. thanks for your help.

Comment: Each line contains "username[space]password".  You'll need to split the line at the space and compare the username to the portion of the line before the split.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
std::ofstream outRegister("account.dat", std::ios_base::app | std::ios_base::out);


 if ( !outRegister    ) {
    cerr << "File could not be opened" << endl;
    exit( 1 );}
    cout<<"enter your username :";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"enter your password :";
    cin>>b;
    outRegister<<a<<' '<<b;
    cout<<"your account has been created";
```

This code would would work just fine. Because you are opening the file in append mode (`ios_base::app`)
Actually the prototype of `std::ofstream` constructor is (`string, std::ios_base::openmode`)